# python creating an object of a class

Tags: python, class

In the function `read_train_sets()` an empty class is created called `DataSets`. It has no methods or variables. An object called `data_sets` is then created.

My question is, is `data_sets.train` an object of the class `DataSet()`.

Or are you creating a method called `train()` and setting it equal to an object of the `DataSet()` class.

Note that there are two classes called `DataSet` and `DataSets` in the code.

```
import cv2
import os
import glob
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import numpy as np


def load_train(train_path, image_size, classes):
    images = []
    labels = []
    img_names = []
    cls = []

    print('Going to read training images')
    for fields in classes:   
        index = classes.index(fields)
        print('Now going to read {} files (Index: {})'.format(fields, index))
        path = os.path.join(train_path, fields, '*g')
        files = glob.glob(path)
        for fl in files:
            image = cv2.imread(fl)
            image = cv2.resize(image, (image_size, image_size),0,0, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
            image = image.astype(np.float32)
            image = np.multiply(image, 1.0 / 255.0)
            images.append(image)
            label = np.zeros(len(classes))
            label[index] = 1.0
            labels.append(label)
            flbase = os.path.basename(fl)
            img_names.append(flbase)
            cls.append(fields)
    images = np.array(images)
    labels = np.array(labels)
    img_names = np.array(img_names)
    cls = np.array(cls)

    return images, labels, img_names, cls


class DataSet(object):

  def __init__(self, images, labels, img_names, cls):
    self._num_examples = images.shape[0]

    self._images = images
    self._labels = labels
    self._img_names = img_names
    self._cls = cls
    self._epochs_done = 0
    self._index_in_epoch = 0

  @property
  def images(self):
    return self._images

  @property
  def labels(self):
    return self._labels

  @property
  def img_names(self):
    return self._img_names

  @property
  def cls(self):
    return self._cls

  @property
  def num_examples(self):
    return self._num_examples

  @property
  def epochs_done(self):
    return self._epochs_done

  def next_batch(self, batch_size):
    """Return the next `batch_size` examples from this data set."""
    start = self._index_in_epoch
    self._index_in_epoch += batch_size

    if self._index_in_epoch > self._num_examples:
      # After each epoch we update this
      self._epochs_done += 1
      start = 0
      self._index_in_epoch = batch_size
      assert batch_size <= self._num_examples
    end = self._index_in_epoch

    return self._images[start:end], self._labels[start:end], self._img_names[start:end], self._cls[start:end]


def read_train_sets(train_path, image_size, classes, validation_size):
  class DataSets(object):
    pass
  data_sets = DataSets()

  images, labels, img_names, cls = load_train(train_path, image_size, classes)
  images, labels, img_names, cls = shuffle(images, labels, img_names, cls)  

  if isinstance(validation_size, float):
    validation_size = int(validation_size * images.shape[0])

  validation_images = images[:validation_size]
  validation_labels = labels[:validation_size]
  validation_img_names = img_names[:validation_size]
  validation_cls = cls[:validation_size]

  train_images = images[validation_size:]
  train_labels = labels[validation_size:]
  train_img_names = img_names[validation_size:]
  train_cls = cls[validation_size:]

  data_sets.train = DataSet(train_images, train_labels, train_img_names, train_cls)
  data_sets.valid = DataSet(validation_images, validation_labels, validation_img_names, validation_cls)

  return data_sets
```

Comment: `data_sets.train = DataSet(... ` tells you that `data_sets.train` is a `DataSet` object. Why are you uncertain?

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm new to python coming from c and some c++. The `.train` suggests your calling a method called `train` on the `data_sets` object. But there isn't a method called `train` defined in the `DataSets` class.

Comment: Python allows you to dynamically add properties to an object. In that sense it is closer to JavaScript than C++. Even though it is possible to do so, it isn't used heavily in Python. Personally, I don't like this idiom of creating an empty class and then adding properties to its objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically assign attributes to your objects in Python. Try inserting `hasattr(data_sets, 'train')` which asks if `data_sets` has attribute `train` after you assign it and see what you get. Also you can call `type(data_sets.train)` and convince yourself that it is indeed of type DataSet.

Comment: thanks - is the reason or benefit for defining the `DataSets` class inside the `read_train_sets()` function purely to limit its scope. I don't see the advantage of it. If you could comment. Thanks

Comment: I don't see much benefit in defining it inside your function and it does seem a bit unusual but i may be wrong. I almost exclusively encounter (and practice) class definitions in the global scope, so at the top level of the module, just like your DataSet class.

Answer (score 0):

```
data_sets.train = DataSet(train_images, train_labels, train_img_names, train_cls)
```

This is quite clear since we are assigning a Class object to the data_sets.train
With respect to data_sets object, train and validate will be 2 attributes to it. Hope this helps.